# Заменить слова из текста ключами из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив вида

```
Array
(
    [0] => Soflyy T-Shirt (blue)
    [1] => 999-B
    [2] => 999-X
    [3] => 15 
    [4] => blue
    [5] => red
)
```

И есть текст вида

```
"Пример текста [0], простой [1] пример текста [2]"
```

Надо заменить в тексте [0], [1] и.д. на соответствующие ключи в массиве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмем ключи функцией array_keys, при помощи array_map добавим скобки, и дальше поменяем через str_relace

```
$ar = Array
(
    'Soflyy T-Shirt (blue)',
    '999-B',
    '999-X');
    $str = "Пример текста [0], простой [1] пример текста [2]";

echo str_replace ( array_map(function ($v)  { return '['.$v.']'; }, array_keys($ar)), $ar, $str);
```

результат

```
Пример текста Soflyy T-Shirt (blue), простой 999-B пример текста 999-X
```